# How do I put a difference query of time (DATEDIFF) in codeigniter active records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get the difference of todays date with the date that is saved in the database table called enter_date using codeigniters active records to only give me the rows that have a 24 hour difference from the enter_date

86400 are the seconds in 24 hours

> Database error: A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DATEDIFF(2016-10-16, `2016-10-17)` = 86400 FROM (`table`)' at
>   line 1
>
> SELECT `table`.`enter_date` AS enter_date DATEDIFF(enter_date,
>   `2016-10-17)` = 86400 FROM (`table`)

and my exact query in codeigniter is:

```
public function get_all(){
            $this->db->select('
            table.enter_date AS enter_date DATEDIFF(enter_date, '.date("Y-m-d").') = 1
        ',FALSE);
    return $this->db->get($this->table);
}
```

also tried:

```
public function get_all(){
            $this->db->select("
            table.enter_date AS enter_date 
        ",FALSE);
            $this->db->where("DATEDIFF(enter_date , '".date("Y-m-d")."')", 1);
    return $this->db->get($this->table);
}
```

Comment: i think u want to add `DATEDIFF(enter_date, 2016-10-17) = 86400` in where clause?

Comment: i tried but it also did not work

Comment: try this: `$this->db->select('
table.enter_date AS enter_date DATEDIFF(enter_date, "'.date("Y-m-d").'") = 86400
'.FALSE);`